# Bound RadioButtonList

Tags: wpf, listbox, radio-button

can someone help me?
I want to bind a list of RadioButtons in a Datatemplate of a ListBox, but it's not acting as a RadioButtonList, i.e. it's enabled to select mulitple RBs at the same time.
I looked online but could not find a correct answer
Thanks for any help

my xaml is as follow

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="itcPayTypes" DockPanel.Dock="Top" BorderThickness="0">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <RadioButton Content="{Binding PayTypeName}"  Click="RadioButton_Click_1"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.   Spell check, format, and post code.

Comment: You're right, I can not write English well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Set same GroupName for all RadioButtons. I hope this will help.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
     <RadioButton Content="{Binding PayTypeName}" GroupName="abc" Click="RadioButton_Click_1"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: It does not help me, because I do not know how buttons appear on the list, because it is a bound list

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I wrote it it in the question

Comment: Seems a good solution, I'll check it later, and then I vote The answer, for now I'm doing something else. Thanks anyway